# React JS filtering according to dropdown criteria chosen by user (several criteria)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

My question concerns React JS specifically, as my assignment must be done in it.  I'm trying to filter a set of static data (kept in a local data.js) by three criteria: date, range and price.

I still need to create a component to display the results, but I don't know where to nest it.

What I have so far:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './Znajdz.css';
import data from './data.js';
// import Box from './Box.js';


export default function Znajdz() {
    const [filteredObiekt, setFilteredObiekt] = useState([]);
    const [date, setDate] = useState([]);
    const [guest, setGuest] = useState('50');
    const [price, setPrice] = useState('100');

  const filterObiekt = function () {
    // event.preventDefault();
    // console.log(guest, data);
    const when = data.filter((obiekt) => obiekt.available === date);
    const prods = data.filter((obiekt) => {
            return obiekt.guests.min >= parseInt(guest.split('-')[0]) && obiekt.guests.max <= parseInt(guest.split('-')[1]);
        }); //parswint
    const money = data.filter((obiekt) => {
        return obiekt.price >= parseInt(price.split('-')[0]) && obiekt.price <= parseInt(price.split('-')[1]);
    });
    // console.log(money, prods, when);
    setFilteredObiekt(prods, when, money);
    
  };
  
    return (
        <div className="search-bar">
            <form className="search-form" onSubmit={(event) => filterObiekt(event)}>
                <input className="search-field" type="date" placeholder="data..." onChange={(e)=>setDate(e.target.value)}/>
                <div className="select">
                    <select type="number" id="guest-select" onChange={(e)=>setGuest(e.target.value)}>
                        <option value="liczba">liczba gości...</option>
                        <option value={'5-20'}>5 - 20</option>
                        <option value={'21-50'}>21 - 50</option>
                        <option value={'51-300'}>51 - 300</option>
                        <option value={'301-999'}>300+ </option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="price-select" type="number" onChange={(e)=>setPrice(e.target.value)}>
                        <option value="cena">cena/os. ...</option>
                        <option value={'0-199'}>poniżej 200PLN</option>
                        <option value={'201-300'}>200 - 300PLN</option>
                        <option value={'301-400'}>300 - 400PLN</option>
                        <option value={'401-999'}>powyżej 400PLN</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                
                <input className="search-field" type="submit" value="Znajdź"></input>
            </form>
        {filteredObiekt.map((obj, index) => {
            return (
                console.log('hello')
        //  <div key={index}>
            
        // <div  obiekt={obj}/>
        //  Hello
        // </div>
        )
        })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

And this is the `data.js`:

```
const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        image: require('../../images/obiekty/Mazurkas/mz1.jpg').default,
        name: "Hotel Mazurkas",
        available: ["2020-01-25", "2021-08-01", "2021-09-12"],
        guests: {min: 20, max:100},// if(x > min && x <= max)
        price: 360,
        opis: "Fantastyczne miejsce na Twoje wesele!  Klimat lat 40 i epoki Art Deco połączony z nowoczesnością, świetną obsługą, oraz wszechstronne możliwości aranżacyjne.  Weselny punkt dla najbardziej wymagających."
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        image: require('../../images/obiekty/Pałac Ojrzanów/po1.jpg').default,
        name: "Pałac Ojrzanów",
        available: ["2021-04-20", "2021-05-04", "2021-05-14", "2021-07-10"],
        guests: {min:5, max:300},
        price: 270,
        opis: "Tradycyjny, elegancki pałac z nostalgicznym wystrojem.  Idealne miejsce na wesele dla miłośników historii i fanów czaru lat minionych. Klasyczne wnętrza, miła obsługa, możliwość zorganizowania ślubu w plenerze w pałacowym ogrodzie."
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        image: require('../../images/obiekty/Pałac Aleksandrinum/pa1.jpg').default,
        name: "Hotel Pałac Aleksandrinum",
        available: ["2021-04-22", "2021-06-04", "2021-05-14", "2021-09-10"],
        guests: {min:50, max:700},
        price: 190,
        opis: "W całości odbudowany pałac przedwojennych hrabiów, zmodernizowany i uzupełniony o wszelkie wygody, przy zachowaniu oryginalnego klimatu. Miejsce na wesele dla tych, co lubią subtelny przepych i luksus."
    },
];

export default data;
```

And this is my Box component.  It's just here to render the data.js stuff in a nice visual way on the webpage:

```
import React from "react";
import './box.css';

const Box = props => {
        return (
            <div className="box-container">
                <img className="box-venue-image" alt="Miejsce na Twoje wesele" src={props.obiekt.image}/>
                <h2 className="box-venue-title">
                    {props.obiekt.name}
                    </h2>
                <div className="box-dates">Dostępność: 
                    <select className="box-dates-select">
                    <option className="box-dates-check" value="0">Sprawdź</option>
                    {props.obiekt.available.map(date => 
                        <option className="box-dates-option" value={date}>{date}</option>
                    )}
                    </select>               
                </div>
                <div className="box-guest-price-container">
                    <h4 className="box-guest-number">
                    {props.obiekt.guests.min} - {props.obiekt.guests.max} osób
                        </h4>
                    <h4 className="box-price">
                    {props.obiekt.price} PLN/os.
                        </h4>
                </div>
                <p className="box-venue-description">
                    {props.obiekt.opis}
                    </p>
            </div>
            
            )
    }

export default Box;
```

My console does not show any errors so I'm led to believe the component renders somewhere, with the filtered data inside it, I just can't see it on the page.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What is `<Box>` ? Your `Box` component should render the data in `obj` .  Import `useState`   as a named import - example `import React, { useState } from 'react'`. Still if you get any errors please post that

Comment: @kiranvj That's the thing - console shows nothing, no errors.  But neither does it log what I'm asking it to when I check if Box renders correctly.  I'm adding Box code above.  It's a component used to display the data.js info in a nice visual manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use state in the same function components to display refer useState in React hooks.

You need to import the useState, similar to react as follows

`import React, { useState } from 'react';`

Comment: can you give me an example, like a code snippet or something?  I'm brand new to React and Hooks.  I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Updated the answer, you can refer to it